# Authoritative Forwarding Bind9

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I have a server that I am running an authoritative DNS server on.

I have a group of servers that I would like to be public facing and forward requests to the root authoritative server on.

How can I make the public facing group of servers return authoritative responses for forwarded requests?

This is my current config:

```
options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";
#filter-aaaa-on-v4 yes;
check-names master ignore;

  response-policy { zone "rpz"; };

        recursion yes;
        allow-query { any; };

        forwarders {
                root authoritative server;
                another root authoritative server;
        };

        dnssec-validation no;

        auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
        listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
```

Answer (score 2):

*Forwarding* in BIND is a recursion feature, it's not useful in an authoritative setting.
Not only does it not return authoritative answers, forwarding is not used in the first place unless recursion is enabled/allowed and the incoming queries have the `RD` (recursion desired) flag set.

You're not very clear about your actual use-case for this, but your desire for authoritative answers suggests that the clients are not asking for recursion (if they were asking for recursion, authoritative answers wouldn't be expected), ie it appears that `RD` will not be set and if that is the case the problems with your intended approach are even bigger than the question suggests.

If what you actually want is a DNS reverse-proxy that you can stick in front of authoritative servers (this is my suspicion based on your desire for authoritative answers from something that passes the queries on elsewhere), that is not what BIND is. Something like [dnsdist](https://dnsdist.org/) could however be configured for that purpose.